# Rigify sit on ground pose (weird leg deformation)

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify

i’m trying to make a pose for a character who is sitting on the ground. I am using the Human rig from Rigify. However, however i make the rig, when trying to position the legs in front of the torso it creates this weird mass in the center. Any way to prevent this?
(Checking “Preserve Volume” does not get rid of the mass)
This is the rig i made. I get the hip is positioned too low, but i already trying bringing it upwards and it does not change
[image]

[image]

Comment: without seeing any of your settings....i would recommend providing your blend file so we can check it out